# Populate Related Field Based on Query Parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a way to show full details of a related field, rather than just the ID or a specific field, when it is specified in a query parameter, e.g http://api_url/courses?populate="author"

Currently, the ID of the author field is shown like so, with this URL - http://api_url/courses

```
"data": [
    {
   
        "author": "e1d5b311-f6b5-4909-8caf-da6ff025a4fc",
        .... 
    }
]
```

I need it to be able to be displayed in full when a ?populate="author" parameter is added to the URL - http://api_url/courses?populate="author" should show this:

```
 "data": [
    {
   
        "author": {
             "id" : "e1d5b311-f6b5-4909-8caf-da6ff025a4fc",
             "first_name" : "string",
             "last_name" : "string",
         },
        .... 
    }
]
```

I can currently show full details of the field by using a nested serializer, like so, or show just the UUID (or any other field) using a SlugRelatedField.

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: so what? what is your question?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov I have edited the question to make it clearer Sir.

Comment: Can you please add the content in the views.py file?